# Javascript failed after 2 functions even though same functions

Tags: javascript, html

This was the html. All had the same style except color.

---

```
<div id="expansion">
<div id="e1" style="display:none;">
    <p style="font-size:36px; color: green;">*</p>
</div>
<div id="e2" style="display:none;">
    <p style="font-size:36px; color: blue;">**</p>
</div>
<div id="e3" style="display:none;">
    <p style="font-size:36px; color: green;">***</p>
</div>
<div id="e4" style="display:none;">
    <p style="font-size:36px; color: blue;">****</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function reflection1() {
    var element=document .getElementById("e2", "e3", "e4").style.display="none";
    var element=document .getElementById("e1").style.display="";
}

function reflection2() {
    var element=document .getElementById("e1", "e3", "e4").style.display="none";
    var element=document .getElementById("e2").style.display="";
}

function reflection3() {
    var element=document .getElementById("e3").style.display="";
    var element=document .getElementById("e1", "e2", "e4").style.display=" none";
}

function reflection4() {
    var element=document .getElementById("e4").style.display="";
    var element=document .getElementById("e1", "e2", "e3").style.display=" none";
}
```

But only function `reflection1()` and `reflection2()` works, 3 and 4 doesnt. Is there a problem in the code?

Comment: when these functions are getting called.

Comment: `.getGetElementById` with multiple ids should never have worked in the first case.

Comment: all your functions work for me. Show us how you call them

Comment: What is the requirement .. and a jdfiddle will be more helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
var element=document .getElementById("e1").style.display="";
```

is valid and this will set the style property to "" (nothing) and hence will be displayed.

But the other statements like

```
var element=document .getElementById("e1", "e3", "e4").style.display="none";
```

is syntactically wrong and hence wont give any result.

To set the display property use the following

```
document.getElementById("<id of element>").style.display="none"; // hidden
document.getElementById("<id of element>").style.display="block"; // visible
```

you dont have to assign anything back

**Edit 1**

[Is this what you are looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/L4jVA/4/)

Comment: I think it is a typo not the actual code.

Comment: @putvande: i just pointed out the invalids in the code

Comment: cause i just wanted to save the amount of lines needed, thus had the code to insert more than one id in get element by id. However that (your answer) works too.